# Iterative pairwise correlation clustering in Python

Tags: python, iteration, cluster-analysis, correlation

I have a correlation matrix of stock returns and want to apply a clustering algorithm to group correlations in an iterative way that groups, recalculates the correlation matrix in each iteration in python.

I've used K-means, agglomerative hierarchical clustering. Neither seems to process the data in the way I would like. agglomerative hierarchical is probably the closest I've found.

I've used K-means and agglomerative hierarchical clustering. Neither seems to process the data in the way I would like.

Neither seems to process the data in the way I would like. Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is find the highest pairwise correlation, group this pair into a single "security" then re-run the correlation table. So, the correlation matrix become and n-1 by n-1 correlation matrix. After the next correlation step is complete, grouping is ran again finding the highest correlation to the initial group. Multiple rounds of this process are ran until the correlation between the larger group and a single security is less than another pairwise correlation in the table. Once this happens, a new group is started and continues until all positive correlation pairs have been used.

Is there a Python clustering algorithm that processes data in this way? I've done a bunch of searching online and studying of the various algos and haven't found one that processes data in this iterative approach in relation to a correlation matrix. If I had to write this function from scratch, I'm not sure where I would need to begin.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an out of the box algorithm to me. This seems like a custom algorithm.

Comment: You may want to de-duplicate the text of your question first. Then why don't you just implement the algorithm exactly as you explain it? It's a version of hierarchical clustering.

Comment: I have not implemented it, because I'm not sure how to at the moment.I thought I would ask the question on the existence of an algorithm meeting my needs first before trying to develop it on my own. I'm fairly new to Python programming and would rather not re-invent something that already exists. Based upon the research that I have done, it does seem custom, but didn't want to assume that was the case.